# Why does this SoapUI assertion, which is checking for a path, fail if the path does not exist?

Tags: soapui

I have a JSONPath Existence assertion in SoapUI:

[image]

The assertion should **pass** if the path `$personResults[0].person.identifiers[0].value` does not exist.

But the assertion always fails with an error:

> Assertion failed for path [$personResults[0].person.identifiers[0].value] : PathNotFoundException:Path 'person' not found in the current context: ... (json request here)

This is indubitably because `$personResults[0].person` does not exist, thus neither does `$personResults[0].person.identifiers`.

... But that's exactly what I'm trying to test!! The assertion needs to **pass** if the path does not exist, yet the assertion is itself throwing an error because the path does not exist.

I am sure that this is due to the path not existing because the assertion fixes if I point it to a path that does exist.

To summarize:

- `$personResults[0]` returns true
- `$personResults[0].person` returns false
- `$personResults[0].person.identifiers` throws a
  `PathNotFoundException`

But I need the lase one to return false.

Answer (score 2):

The JSONPath engine that SoapUI uses is not as full-fledged as you might like.

The workaround is to use XPath. Internally SoapUI converts everything to XML, and so you just use an XPath match step:

```
exists(//*:personResults//*:person//*:identifiers)
```

expecting:

```
false
```

Edit: You might need to add namespaces, as edited above.

Comment: Ok, `exists(//personResults//person//identifiers)` does, indeed, return `false`. But so does everything else I put in there, such as `exists(//personResults)` which I expected to return true.

Comment: The problem with this expression is the omission of the namespace, which is covered in the answer with "*:".

Comment: One caveat I'd like to add has to do with how SoapUI converts JSON into XML.  One of the JSON entities in my output included characters that could not be used in XML or XPath, e.g. service/{serviceId}/path as an element name.  When SoapUI converts this into an XML element, it will be converted to camel case without special characters, e.g. serviceServiceIdPath.  In this case, to use the XPath function exists on this element, the expression would look like

    exists(//*:serviceServiceIdPath)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a script assertion:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def TrimResponse = ResponseMessage.replaceAll('^\"|\"$','').replaceAll('/\\/','')
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(TrimResponse)

assert (
    jsonSlurper.personResults[0].person == null
    || jsonSlurper.personResults[0].person.identifiers == null
)
```