# How to validate JSONpath exist or not using groovy in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsonpath

In the SoapUi version 5.7.0, can not validate assertions using JSONpath existence match assertion tools is throwing invalid JSON path as attached in the screenshot
Please suggest how to handle this using groovy in SoapUi. It is working fine with version 5.6.0
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53054188/why-does-this-soapui-assertion-which-is-checking-for-a-path-fail-if-the-path-d).  One caveat I'd like to add has to do with how SoapUI converts JSON into XML.  One of the JSON entities in my output included characters that could not be used in XML or XPath, e.g. service/{serviceId}/path as an element name.  When SoapUI converts this into an XML element, it will be converted to camel case without special characters, e.g. serviceServiceIdPath.  In this case, to use the XPath function exists on this element, the expression would look like

```
exists(//*:serviceServiceIdPath)
```